# How to detect which submit button is clicked in a web form using jquery

Tags: jquery, submit

If I have 2 submit buttons on a form:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 1">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Button 2">
```

I have this jquery but every time I click button 2 I get the alert for button 1.

```
$('form.profile').submit(function() {
if ($("input[type=submit]").val() == 'Button 1')
{
alert('you clicked button 1');
return false;
}
elseif ($("input[type=submit]").val() == 'Button 2')
{
alert('you clicked button 2');
return false;
}
});
```

I need to perform form validation before the form is sent to the server and I need to be able to determine which of the 2 buttons was clicked.

Is it possible to identify which of the 2 buttons caused the form to be submitted using jquery?

Comment: May I ask why not use an ID ?

Comment: Sure @DimitarDimitrov. I am not sure how the `id` versus the `name` makes a difference in intercepting which of the 2 buttons is being clicked. So I have gone down the `name` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help!!!  http://jsfiddle.net/hun4U/

Instead of formSubmission you can use click events.

HTML:-

```
<input name="submit" id="submit1" type="submit" value="Button 1">
<input name="submit" id="submit2" type="submit" value="Button 2">
```

Script

```
$('#submit1').click(function(){
//do your actions here
});

$('#submit2').click(function(){
    //do your actions here
    });
```

Comment: It really doesn't help @PSCoder. I already knew about the .click() What I need to do is form validation and I need to do a different validation based on which of the 2 buttons were clicked prior to sending the request back to the server. So I need to work within the .submit() and not do a direct .click() call.

Comment: Surprisingly you accepted this as answer after a long time. Thank you!!. But i thought initially you had it downvoted... :)