# How identify the form submit button clicked in a variable using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can I assign the id of a submit button to a variable using JQuery?

I have the following HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="oknovo" type="submit" value="OK & Novo" />
    <input id="okfechar" type="submit" value="OK & Fechar" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
var botao;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm input[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
        botao = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("id é " + botao);
    });
});
```

You may see the live [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3fJ3r/7/)

I've already managed to indentify the clicked button wiht the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15538501/how-to-detect-which-submit-button-is-clicked-in-a-web-form-using-jquery) but the problem now is to assign it to a [global variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5786851/define-global-variable-in-a-javascript-function)

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Why not using submit method?

Comment: @RajeshDhiman — Because then you couldn't tell which button was clicked.

Comment: @Quentin sir thats perfect catch/

Comment: what about using "window.botao"?

Comment: The form is going to refresh the page and the global variable is going to get replaced, what is the use of setting the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, you just need to add the closing parenthesis `)` at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                 ^ unclosed
```

Comment: I was assuming that was a copy/paste error when forming the question, since the text does say "I've already managed to indentify the clicked button"

Comment: @NunoNogueira If this happens more often, it might be a good idea that whenever you need to type `(`, you type `)` immediately and then move the caret in between. That way, you can never forget any :)

Comment: @Thoronwen thanks! The thing is I'm used to Aptana IDE (it does that for me). JSFiddle doesn't... :-)

Answer (score 2):

> the problem now is to assign it to a global variable.

Either remove the line `var botao;` or take it out of the function you are calling `onload` (via the JSFiddle configuration on the left).

Comment: Removing the line var botao; won't help. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/3fJ3r/8/

Comment: @NunoNogueira I dont understand real issue.

Comment: @NunoNogueira — The error there is `);` is missing from your call to `ready`. The code to assign to a global is fine.

Comment: @Pilot the line alert("id é " + botao); results in an error

Comment: @NunoNogueira — No, it doesn't (the only error is described in my last comment, and I was assuming that was a copy/paste problem when forming the question since you said you were successfully getting the value) … and that comes after you assign `botao` to a global (which is what you claim the problem is) anyway.

Comment: @NunoNogueira I dont see any error..as Quentin master said you are just missing `);`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing brackets on your fiddle. It should read:

```
var botao;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm input[type=submit]").click(function (event) {
        botao = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("id é " + botao);
    });
});
```

Comment: I was assuming that was a copy/paste error when forming the question, since the text does say "I've already managed to indentify the clicked button"

Answer (score 0):

This question does not makes any sense, since code looks like working except syntax errors; on the other hand, you can use hidden fields to keep some data for temporary.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id='myGlobalHidden' type='hidden'/>
    <input id="oknovo" type="button" value="OK & Novo" />
    <input id="okfechar" type="button" value="OK & Fechar" />
</form>


var botao;
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#myForm input[type=button]").click(function (event) {
                botao = $(this).attr('id');
        //alert("id é " + botao);
        $("#myGlobalHidden").val(botao);
        // access here
        alert($("#myGlobalHidden").val());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3fJ3r/10/